# GCP Error disabling a hybrid partner interconnect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-interconnect

I am trying to create a hybrid partner interconnect with Equinix as the partner using the GCP REST API. I have done this successfully many times using the the same process that I used this time.

This time, when I created the hybrid interconnects using the REST API, I could create the primary and secondary interconnects, their corresponding connections on the partner side, and attach them to a cloud router as usual. However, the redundant secondary interconnect was stuck in "Waiting for partner".

I didn't bother configuring BGP routing for the primary and started deleting the interconnects using the GCP console so that I could try again.

I could delete both connections on the Equinix side and the secondary interconnect on the GCP side successfully, but I can't disable/delete the primary interconnect.

I get an error that "The resource 'projects/xxxx/regions/us-west1/interconnectAttachments/xxxx' is not ready".

Has anybody seen this happen? How do I delete this interconnect?

Thanks,
Venu

Answer (score 0):

Usually a common cause of this error is that the VLAN didn't get fully set up and it stays in a pending status, so it isn't allowed to be deleted;

If everything is/was correctly deleted, this could be a propagation delay on the backend server. I would give a 24-48h, if the interconnect is not deleted, I would try again.

From that point, if this doesn't resolve the issue, you should reach out to GCP support if you have a support package.

Or

You can reach out to your Partner and ask them to investigate this issue.

Some additional articles regarding deleting Interconnect:

- [Deleting Interconnects](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/dedicated/deleting-interconnects)
- [Disconnecting Networks](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/partner/deleting-vlans)
- [gcloud beta compute interconnects attachments delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/interconnects/attachments/delete)
- You can also click on "send feedback" to get a Cloud Interconnect team to support you directly [Getting support](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/support/getting-support)